# Could not resolve dependencies for maven multi module project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, multi-module

I've created a multi module Maven project in Intellij. The structure is the following

```
parent
     |-module1
     |
     |-module2
     |
     |-module3
```

First I tried to build the parent module, everything was fine. But then I added a class in module2 and used it in module1. So I added a dependency in module1 pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

But when I try to build the parent (or the module1 as well)- I get the following

```
[INFO] Building 2 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.example:module2:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.188 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-02T23:29:35+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project module1: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:module1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.example:module2:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

As I understand it tries to download the dependency from the central maven repository. I don't have any repository con1figurations at all.
I am running out of ideas what else to try.

Can you help to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the ordering of your module builds - as specified in the parent POM. Module1 requires a class from module2, and that module (module2) is not yet built. Try swapping the ordering of module1 and module2 in the parent POM so that module2 is built before module1.

Comment: Switched module1 and module2 in parent pom.xml and still get the same issue.

Comment: Can you print the result of running a mvn clean install on the parent POM?

Comment: Still getting [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project module1: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:module1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.example:module2:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1].

Comment: I can’t help without seeing your command and the entire output from running it, can you copy and paste all of that here so I can see it?

Comment: It would also be worth revealing all three POM files as well.